# asp.net mvc routing clean address bar

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When using razor url.action calls,

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Profile", new { ThemeCode = 'SOC' })">
```

Then I get this link in the adress bar

> xxx.com/Profile?ThemeCode=SOC

I want to send the attribute to the index method in profile controller, but I also want a more clean appearance in the adress bar.

Like this:

> xxx.com/soc

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a specific route, for example (assuming you also want the default route to be `/Home/Index`)

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

  routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Profile",
    url: "Profile/{action}/{ThemeCode}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Profile", action = "Index", ThemeCode  = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );

  routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Task", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. Ill try that. How do you call it with URL.Action?? Could I do this: <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Profile", new { ThemeCode = 'Social' })"> and get xxx.com/Social ??

Comment: Yes, assuming your `ProfileController` has `public ActionResult(string ThemeCode)`

Comment: Or with `@Html.ActionLink(linkText, "Index", "Profile", new { ThemeCode = "Social" }, null)`, but in both cases, only if you make this the default route - `url: "{controller}/{action}/{ThemeCode}", defaults: new { controller = "Profile", action = "Index", ThemeCode = UrlParameter.Optional }`

Comment: I still get xxx.com/Profile?ThemeCode=SOC. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure you have an `Index` method with a parameter named ThemeCode? - ii.e. `public ActionResult Index(string ThemeCode)`

Comment: Yes.. I got it to work, but not as expected. If I use xxx.com/Profile/Index/Social it works, if the Profile Route mapping is before Default routing. If Default routing is after Profile Routing, then I have other plug ins not working. Like Tinymce that i used in the Profile views. The link is not xxx.com/Social, is it possible with routing and not desturbing all other code using these routes?

Comment: I haven't used `Tinymce` so can't really comment on how it may be affecting your routing or if its causing a problem (:

Comment: I think I can create custom routing for Tinymce. The problem is xxx.com/Social :) I dont want xxx.com/Profile/Index/Social..

Comment: Then your route would need to be just `url: "{ThemeCode}", defaults: new { controller = "Profile", action = "Index" }`. You could call this in an `ActionLink()` e.g. `@Html.ActionLink(linkText, "Index", "Profile", new { ThemeCode = "Social" }, null)` or `Url.Action()`. This would need to be the first route (but do you really want it that anything that a user types in the address bar is directed to this controller method?)

Comment: No thats not what I wants.. I created a little work around.. I created at dummy controller for Social and Redirect to Profile controller - Method Social, and this gives me: xxx.com/Profile/Social. That looks fine and working without changing the routing..

Answer (score 0):

Could I create a catchall for all none valid adresses?
Like xxx.com/Profile/Social123 should not give servererror, but redirect to home controller etc..